# SSL handshake fails for google.com only, in all browsers

Tags: macos, ssl, osx-mavericks, ssl-certificate, avast

I can't connect to `google.com` via HTTPS on any browser (Safari, Firefox or Chrome). All other sites (HTTPS or not) are fine. The error I get is `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` in Chrome, `Secure Connection Failed` in Firefox. Both `curl` and `OpenSSL` via command line also fail:

```
$ curl https://www.google.com
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake

$ OpenSSL s_client -connect www.google.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
333:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.8.4/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:185:
```

I have tried "Reset my default keychain" and a lot of other suggestions, but nothing has worked. I recently installed AVAST (which has worked fine for a couple of weeks) and I think the problem may have something to do with AVAST hijacking the SSL process - I have now uninstalled it but still have the same problem.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem, and have not installed AVAST or any similar application that might interfere with SSL. It only affects OSX Mavericks, not my Yosemite system, and the connections work fine in a Windows XP VM on the affected machine. Looks like this could be a bug on Google's side?

Comment: I have the same problem. No Avast here, and e.g. mail.google.com or groups.google.com are not affected. OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: 10.9.5 here too.

Comment: docs.google.com, account.google.com, support.google.com and youtube.com are also affected for me.

Comment: @DanielBeck, James - mine is now working.

Comment: This is also now working for us. I can only conclude this was a screwed up configuration from Google.

Comment: disfunctional google service (but working internet otherwise) tends to be a problem with DNS roots. Check VPN-, OS- and router DNS settings.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it was a problem with Google as the remote end aborted the SSL handshake.

If it had been just your machine it cURL would have simply stated `alert handshake failure` if it was your machine.

While I know this is an answer to an old question, I hope it helps anyone else who runs into this problem.